# Help with Discrete Probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, permutations

I'm trying to show statistics related to combinations of discrete variables. I have a feeling what I need to do is quite simple but I can't for the life of me remember the correct formulas to achieve this. I've been reading [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98870/combinations-and-probabilities) which has been useful but unfortunately doesn't touch upon my specific questions. I will phrase the problem in the following way.

There are **sixteen** (n) possible ice-cream flavours. Each flavour has an infinite amount of ice-cream i.e. repition is allowed and has equal probability.

There are **sixty-four** (r) children. Each is allowed to choose one ice-cream with a flavour of his choice. Their preference is entirely random.

I need some formulas to ask the following questions:

1. What is the probability that between these sixty-four children, all of the possible flavours will be be chosen?
2. What is the probability that all the children will choose a single (but not specified) flavour?
3. What is the probability that all the children will choose a single (and specified) flavour?

Answer (score 0):

Hints in reverse:

- 3) Each of the $64$ children has a $\frac{1}{16}$ probability of choosing the specified flavour
- 2) Like (3) but there are $16$ distinct possible flavours
- 1) Harder.   You might want to think about [Stirling numbers of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)

Comment: Thank you. I've worked out the last two. (3) should be (1/16)^64. (2) should be 16 times (2) or (1/16)^63. (1) is annoying but somebody pointed to the formula: number of successful outcomes / number of total outcomes. The number of total outcomes is 16^64. The number of successful outcomes might be this: (16!)*(16^48). i.e. 16 children have to be unique and the other 48 children can be anything. However reducing this provides a very small number (almost 0 probability). I was expecting a very high number, (almost 1 probability). What happened?